# Red Hat 7.2 GCC version support the compilation of C++14 code?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, redhat

Is RedHat 7.2's GCC C++14 compatible?

If yes where I can find the reference?

Comment: (I am not the downvoter, but...) can you specify what do you mean with compatible?

Comment: What version of g++ is installed?

Comment: thanks a lot. Please which version supports the compilation for C++14

Answer (score 1):

Install the Red Hat Developer Toolset:

https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview

This gives you the latest compiler. Software compiled with it can use the latest C++ standard and it will run fine on systems that do not have the toolset installed.

Answer (score 0):

**The default GCC compiler version for Red Hat 7.2 is the 4.8.x as reported by the [official site](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19458).**

**This version do not support the compilation for C++14.**

Now the back compatibility with older version is granted by Red Hat, but no one speeking about the possibility to go ahead.

An official package (rpm) does not exist, but you can try to compile a newer version of the compiler.

EDIT:

The GCC Version 5.x support the c++14.
The GCC Version 6.x that C++14 as default.

Comment: thanks a lot. Please which version supports the compilation for C++14.